# How to get PrimeFaces editor to expand to available space?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have started to use the PrimeFaces **p:editor** for text input and for the most part I am fairly pleased with how it works. However the documentation notes that the CKEditor on which it is based does not plug into the ThemeRoller framework so the components dimensions do not adjust automatically.

So for example:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">

    (stuff)

    <h:outputLabel value="Content:" />
    <p:editor id="editDoc" widgetVar="editorDoc"
                 value="#{editDocument.text}"
                 style="width: 700px"
                                  />

    (more stuff)
</h:panelGrid>
```

I would like the **p:editor** to expand to the width of the table that **h:panelGrid** renders.  Yet nothing I have tried works.   Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

I should note that the **p:editor** tag pays no attention to the **style** attribute.  Instead it has a **width** attribute and a **height** attribute and they don't work the same way the CSS parameters would work.  For example **width="100%"** is an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual width of the `p:editor` depends on the size of its inner `<div>`. You can simply overwrite that default value:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #editDoc > div {
        width: 99.5% !important;
    }
</style>
```

also remove the `style="width: 700px"` of the `p:editor` and attach it to the `h:panelGrid` instead.

A more general solution which applies to all `p:editor` components is to overwrite the default `width` attribute of the `.ui-editor` class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-editor {
        width: 99.5% !important;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I upvoted, but after a longer test, the solution you give only resizes the toolbar. The inner iframe (where the user types) always has a width around 600px. Is there a solution?

Comment: @geceo please note that this solution may be outdated. I don't know how this behaves with the current PrimeFaces version.

Answer (score 1):

For Primefaces 4, we have to set the width of the inner `iframe`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-editor iframe {
        width:100% !important;
    }
</style>
```